# Rearrangement of the alternating harmonic series exists $\iff\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_n}{q_n} = \alpha$ exists.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

(a) Let $X_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k - \ln(n+1)$ for $n\ge1$.
Express $X_n$ as an area.
Hence show that $X_n < X_{n+1} < 1$ for all $n\ge1$.
Deduce that this sequence has a limit, usually called $\gamma$.

(b) Use (a) to obtain a useful expression for $\sum_{k=1}^{p_n} \frac1{2k-1} -  \sum_{k=1}^{q_n} \frac1{2k}$. Hint $\sum_{k=1}^p \frac1{2k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^{2p} \frac1{k} - \sum_{k=1}^p \frac1{2k}$.

(c) Consider a *simple rearrangement* of the alternating harmonic series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$ that contains the odd terms in order
and the even terms in order, but  the first $n$ term of the series consists of $p_n$ odd terms and $q_n$ even terms.
Prove that the series converges if and only if the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{p_n}{q_n} = \alpha$ exists.
Express the limit as a function of $\alpha$.

---

I've been able to show that it is increasing and bounded by 1 above. And in terms of area, it is the difference between the Riemann sum and the integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ on $[1,n]$.

My problem is part (b) because I'm not sure what a 'useful expression' would be in terms of $X_n$ in order to help with part (c).

Comment: Could you add what you tried already? What do you already know? What do you think you need to solve this problem? etc. Posts sometimes get downvoted if you don't provide that information if it considers an exercise, just that you know.

Comment: I understand, and apologize. I added some information to the question that will maybe help.